# how to run serverside javascript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Hi I wanted to know what are the different ways by which we can run the SSJS(serverside javascript ) on SFMC. One way is to using script activity but i guess we cant track if it executed sucessfully. 
Can anybody please provide other method where i can track the execution

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in debugging/testing out SSJS before committng to an Automation Studio Script activity, you can use:

- One-off test emails (for in-browser previewing; not recommended for production sending due to performance)
- CloudPages or landing pages

Comment: HI thanks for the reply but since i am new to marketing cloud i am not able to get CloudPages or landing Pages term  can u please provide more clarity or complete procedure to run

Comment: @user69817 Do you at least have Content Builder to create an email? You can follow the steps [outlined here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_emails.htm&type=5).